# How to snap a vertice to an edge without actual snapping it to that edge, staying on your native plane?

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

I accidently move the point of my prism. I need it back on that same place it was, just like the left part on the picture. I use constrains in X axes and want to align the vertice position with that far edge on the opposite side. And it just doesn't work. [image]
I tried every possible manipulations and struggle to solve this riddle by myself.
Please, help, good people. It is very easy to reproduce. Please :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the worst case; no alignment to local or global axes..

My snap is nearly always set to 'To: Vertex' and  'With: Active'. I find it covers the great majority of cases.

Also, 'Create Orientation' (The little  '**+**' in the Transform Orientation pop-up) is used so often, it's in my Quick Favorites. If you use it a lot, it might be a good idea to set it to 'Overwrite Previous', first time round.

If you create an orientation from any two points, or an edge, the direction along it is Y. So the operation looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not exact my situation, but YES! Yes, it is the solution I was searching for. Thank you so much. Will use custom orientations more from now on.

Comment: @TRUEvector Great! Bear in mind this _is_ a personal habit.. I still get blown away every now and then by tutorials, or answers here,  showing me better ways to do most everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do, I assume you're trying to restore symmetry of your mesh. It would be trivial if the plane of symmetry was aligned with some axes, e.g. XZ. but the screenshot doesn't show that, so here's instructions that may work regardless of the meshes orientation:

0. Skip to p. 7. If the point you want to move is exactly at the center of (desired) symmetry.
1. Select an edge that is parallel to the edge of interest, and is already symmetric (the middle of the edge is in the center of symmetry).
2. If this edge is aligned (parallel) to the $y$ axis, you can skip this step. Otherwise press <kbd>F3</kbd> `Create Orientation`, or click the plus in the orientation menu:

[image]

3. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd> to move *3D Cursor* to the center of the edge (therefore the center of symmetry).
4. <kbd>.</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to set *Pivot Point* to the *3D Cursor*.
5. <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to vertex selection mode.
6. <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> To move the vertex towards the 3D cursor, but only perpendicularly to the plane of symmetry (only towards/away to/from the mirror).

[image]

7. <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> for Vertex Slide, move your mouse to tell Blender which edge to slide on (the edge of interest), <kbd>1</kbd> to slide all the way, <kbd>-</kbd> to reverse the direction, <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
And thank you for your respond. Unfortunately no, I was not talking about the point in the center, I meant the opposite side, to restore the symmetry of the prism (I showed with red dot the place where the selected point shoud be).
Nevertheless, your comment was invalueble, because I've learnt how to use custom orientations.
Also, I just found out rather quick solution how to fix such prisms with triangulating the desired face and snaping the point to it.